# How do I make my system crontab fetch a URL and email it to me?

Tags: cron

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 with Apache module. I opened crontab by executing `vi /etc/crontab`

It says on the top that *unlike any other crontab you don't have to run the 'crontab' command to install the new version*. So I don't have to run crontab crontab? Even if I am trying to execute it I receive the error

```
crontab: No such file or directory
```

I added this to the crontab file (there are 4 default jobs there):

```
*/1 * * * * root http://www.mywebsite.com/crondemo.php
```

This file should send me a mail every minute. The script itself works fine, but the job never runs and I never get a mail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A crontab entry must be an executable shell command. A URL is not an executable shell command. Try `*/1 * * * * root wget -q -O- http://www.mywebsite.com/crondemo.php` instead. `wget` is a command that fetches a URL. `-q` tells wget to not print progress, and `-O-` tells it to output the fetched URL to stdout, which cron will then email.

If you want to receive emails from cron, make sure you set `MAILTO` correctly above the relevant job in your crontab, and make sure that your system MTA works. You can use the `mail` command to test this.

The contents of `/var/log/syslog` may also help you diagnose cron problems, since cron will log jog attempts there even if it can't email you (provided that your crontab is installed and correctly provides a job schedule).

Finally, the comment is correct. As an exception, changes to `/etc/crontab` are picked up automatically.